# Vue trigger mounted before async created completed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

VueJS fires `mounted` before `async created` done.

The base html is rendered by SSR (Laravel/PHP) for SEO and users. So, it is desirable to complete `this.fetchCakeShops()` and variable `this.cakeShops` is filled before mount `id="cake-shop-list"` to virtual DOM. (Otherwise, the screen become blank until `this.cakeShops` is set) Therefore I wrote code like bellow.

```html
<!-- Base html -->
<div id="cake-shop-list">
 <!-- Already server side rendered cake shops list -->
 <ul><li>shopA</li><li>shopB</li></lu>
</div>
```

```js
<template>
 <div>
   <ul>
     <li v-for="shop in cakeShops" :key="shop.id" :click="onClickShop(shop.id)">{{shop.name}}</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 ...
 async created() {
   console.log("created start!")
   this.cakeShops = await this.fetchCakeShops({page: 1})
   console.log("created ends!", this.cakeShops)
 },
 mounted() {
   console.log("mounted!")
 },
 methods: {
  ...
 }
}
</script>
```

I wish mounted hook starts after created. But the log console shows like bellow, and the DOM is override with blank virtual DOM in a few seconds.

```
created start!
mounted! <- Oops
created ends!
Array(10)[{id: 1, name: 'shopA'},{id: 2, 'shopB'}...]
```

Is there any solution to wait mount until async is complete?

note: I can not pass shops array to `props`.

Comment: [This Github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7209) talks a bit more why and has some workaround for it.

Answer (score 0):

The mounted method will not wait untill the created method is done (event if its async) instead what you could do is create a different function and call this at the end of your create function

this will look something like this:

```
 async created() {
   
   this.cakeShops = await this.fetchCakeShops({page: 1})
   
   this.loaded();
 },

 methods: {
   loaded: {
     //code here
   },
 }
```